# How do I uninstall a package locally in anaconda?

Tags: python, package, anaconda, uninstallation

I am trying to remove a package in anaconda (python) on a Linux server. The system cannot connect to the outside because of firewalls. So I need to do it locally. I tried this:

#conda remove package-name

but it wants to connect to the outside. How can I uninstall a package locally? If I just delete it, would it be uninstalled properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. I think I figured it out. I need to add --offline to the command!